# Turning a JSON result into a dyamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynamic

I'm having a devil of a time creating a dynamic table with MVC (variable column counts). I'm using a json result but using the jquery .each() iterator causes my table columns to sort automatically (Chrome). Is there a way to move the columns?  I need **Name** and **Position** to be first.

```
var data =  
[{"Name":"Craven Moorehead","Position":"SV-WA-1","601036":"x","600001":"x","600003":"x"},{"Name":"Vinny MCCuzin","Position":"SV-TECH-1","601036":"x","600001":"x","600003":"x"},{"Name":"Harold Balzonia","Position":"SV-TECH-0","601036":"x","600001":"x","600003":"x"},{"Name":"Phil  McCrevic","Position":"PT-PM-1","601036":"x","600001":"x","600003":"x"},{"Name":"Hewenta Jared","Position":"SV-TECH-1","601036":"x","600001":"x","600003":"x"}]


    var tablehtml = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>";
            var header = "<thead><tr>";
            var datain = data[0];
            $.each(datain, function (key, value) {                    

                header += "<th>" + key + "</th>";
                console.log(key);
            });
            header += "</tr></thead>";
            var rowhtml = "<tbody>";
            $.each(data, function () {
                rowhtml += "<tr>";
                $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                    /// make a row
                    rowhtml += "<td>";

                    if (v == "x") {

                        rowhtml += "<input type='checkbox'/>";
                    } else {

                        rowhtml += v;
                    }
                    rowhtml+= "</td>";
                });
                rowhtml += "</tr>"
            });

            tablehtml += header + rowhtml + "</tbody></table>";
$("#headers").append(tablehtml);


<pre id="output"></pre>
<pre id="headers"></pre>
```

The output looks like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jzu3nLh/4/)

Comment: create array of field names, loop over that array and use `data[index][field]` for values

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/5jzu3nLh/5/
 
  You can add a space in front of those dynamic column names so the name and position are the first values when sorted.

Comment: If you are using JSON data,I suggest you to use datatables jquery plugin
This ease your work, http://www.datatables.net/